# OPatch in Oracle 12C - Duplicating databases

Tags: oracle-12c

I am new to Oracle 12C.  I am trying to restore the production database with SID 'PROD' into a test server for testing purposes.  In the test server I have kept everything exactly the same as in production server.  However the production server was set up in 2017 and I am creating the test server now.  When I tried to restore the database, I got the following error:

```
ORA-00904: "ACDRROWTSINTCOL#": invalid identifier
```

Online help indicated that I need to do `startup upgrade` at sqlplus.  When I did the same, I got the following error.

```
SQL> startup upgrade;
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 2.6978E+10 bytes
Fixed Size         26330680 bytes
Variable Size        1.3892E+10 bytes
Database Buffers     1.3019E+10 bytes
Redo Buffers           40775680 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-01113: file 1 needs media recovery
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/home/app/oracle/oradata/PROD/system01.dbf'
```

This error lead me to run recover database command.  When I ran this, I got this error.

```
SQL> RECOVER DATABASE USING BACKUP CONTROLFILE UNTIL CANCEL;
ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
ORA-16433: The database or pluggable database must be opened in read/write
mode
```

The exploration on this error lead me to believe that I have to upgrade the `OPatch` in oracle 12c.  When I checked for the OPatch version between production and test server, I found them to be different.

In production it was `OPatch Version: 12.2.0.1.3` and in test it was `OPatch Version: 12.2.0.1.6`.

How do I downgrade the OPatch in my test server.  I do not want to touch production database as the data is critical.

If there is any other work around to resolve this, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: What o/s?Did you download binaries from Oracle or cloned dbhome from prod?

Comment: OS: RHEL6, Downloaded the binaries from Oracle.

Comment: Forget OPatch for now. What are the source and database versions? How did you do the restore? To me it seems the restore and recover part was not properly  executed.

Comment: Looks to me like the source and destination patch levels were different

Comment: @BalazsPapp Both the db version is 12.2.0.1.0.  Restore is done through rman backup with archivelogs.  Backup of controlfile is taken separately.  The restore was done using `duplicate target database to 'prod' backup location '/home/user/bkup/' nofilenamecheck`

Comment: Can you post rman duplicate out put and `select * from v$version` on prod server.